# php mail отправляет по 2 письма

Tags: email, php

```
mail("daemon_07@list.ru", "the subject", 'some text',   
             "From: info@example.ua \r\n"   
            ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Функция отправляет по 2 письма, хотя должна только одно.
Это весь код, файл чистый, только эта функция.

Comment: весь код напиши, где у тебя эта ф-я вызывается.

и пора начать принимать ответы на вопросы!

Comment: это и есть весь код, файл чистый, только эта функция

Comment: криво значит php настроен.

Comment: а в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: а с чего ты решил, что 2 письма отправляется?

Comment: >а в чем может быть проблема ?

в "программисте"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `mail()` у Вас в коде вызывается только раз. Это значит, что и отправляет она тоже только одно письмо. Чудес в программировании не бывает.

Я думаю, что этот код Вы запускаете не в консоли а путем открытия страницы через браузер. 
Скорее всего у Вас просто страница загружается два раза. Это может быть по разным причинам. И это уже тема другого вопроса.

И как, в комментариях, сказал [[@Shrek](/users/4597/shrek)](/users/4597/shrek): "пора бы принимать ответы на вопросы". Так, что будьте добры, пройдитесь по списку ваших вопросов и выставите галочки над тем вопросом, который Вам помог.

Answer (score 1):

У меня метрика запускает второй раз зачем-то, потому пришлось ставить проверку в коде.